# Is there any way to pass the parameter with name while running the c++ program in terminal

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, and want to pass and get the parameters using name(like in perl language) while running the c++ script in terminal.

This is for linux, in the past i a have created a c++ script and running the script like this with passing the arguments "./server arug1 arug2".
But i need to get the arguments with name (eg: "./server --data=arug1 data2=arug2" like in perl) not with argument position (eg:./server arug1 arug2)

Comment: I recommend you read about [`getopt` and more specifically `getopt_long`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it saved my day. And may i know how to validate this kind of exection from the terminal "./server some-text" instead of "./server --some-text=somevalue"

Comment: The examples in the linked manual page should show non-option arguments.